# Ant build fails to mkdir

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, ant

I'm currently trying to get a private server for an older mmo that no longer serves the US going. I am by no means a Java whiz, but I have been googling and beating my head against a wall for several hours now with no luck. I'm using eclipse for this, have both JDK and JRE installed and paths configured.

The build.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="L1J" default="all" basedir=".">
<description>
    This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
    (at your option) any later version.

    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
    GNU General Public License for more details.

    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
    along with this program.  If not, see http://www.gnu.org/licenses/
</description>

<!-- Set Property -->
<property name="src.dir" value="src" />
<property name="lib.dir" value="libs" />
<property name="build.dir" value="build" />
<property name="main.class" value="jp.l1j.Server" />
<property name="jarfile" value="l1jserver.jar" />

<path id="libs">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>
</path>
<pathconvert property="classpath" refid="libs" targetos="windows"  pathsep=" ">
    <map from="${basedir}\${lib.dir}\" to="./${lib.dir}/"/>
    <map from="\" to="/"/>
</pathconvert>

<!-- Set DefaultTarget -->
<target name="all" depends="clean,compile,jar,clean2" />

<!-- clean Target -->
<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
</target>

<!-- Compile Target -->
<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
    <javac includeantruntime="true" srcdir="${src.dir}"
        destdir="${build.dir}"
        optimize="on"
        debug="on"
        encoding="UTF-8">
        <classpath refid="libs" />
        <compilerarg value="-Xlint:unchecked" />
    </javac>
</target>

<!-- jar Target -->
<target name="jar">
    <jar jarfile="${jarfile}" basedir="${build.dir}">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}" />
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${classpath}" />
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>

<!-- clean Target -->
<target name="clean2">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
</target>

</project>
```

The output from Eclipse after running the Build.xml:

```
Buildfile: C:\Users\Administrator\workspace\L1J\build.xml

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\Administrator\workspace\L1J\build.xml:28: C:\Users\Administrator\workspace\L1J\libs does not exist.

Total time: 390 milliseconds
```

I did try manually creating the directories and doing so allows the script to run, but that gives me a "could not find or load main class jp.l1j.server" error when it's run with this start server batch file:

```
@java -server -XX:MetaspaceSize=256m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:NewRatio=2 -XX:SurvivorRatio=8  -jar l1jserver
@pause
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need any third party library to compile or run your application ?
It seems that your classpath is always empty since you had to create the libs directory by hand. I assume that you do not need any dependencies when building your jar since ant build succeed, but maybe you need some at runtime ?

Answer (score 0):

The `fileset` nested inside the `path` with id libs is scanning the directory libs as soon as the `pathconvert` task is executed.  Since `pathconvert` is outside of any `target` it is executed before any `target`.

Besides, I don't see any `mkdir` for `lib.dir` anyway.